# Is every born child a Muslim and belongs to Islam?

Tags: islam

Few months back I asked a [**question**](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26120/why-muslims-want-to-convert-non-muslims-to-islam) about `Why Muslims want to convert non Muslims to Islam` on `Islam Stack Exchange`. All the answers I got was totally disappointing and doesn't answer my question. I thought that they will say that all the religions are equal but instead they said that `Islam` is the only religion which is above every religion

People at `Islam Stack Exchange` answered my question with the different points and I was in shock. They said all other religions are praying to god which never exist. Hindu religion pray to cow or a statue who cannot protect himself so how these are god.

As I was the minority there so I gave up. (If you guys can help me over there, so I am ready for the discussion again).

Well my major doubt is one of the guy from `Islam stack Exchange` said 
    **Every child takes birth as a Muslim. Whether he is born in a Christian household or a Hindu family, he is born a Muslim. But his parents and caretakers make him a Christian, a Jew or other Non-Muslim**

How much is this statement correct?

Comment: Everyone has their own beliefs. It is ridiculous to claim that every human who was born is Muslim. According to Garuda Purana, baby in mother's womb interacts with lord Vishnu but when he comes out of the womb, he forgets everything due to Lord's Maya ( ultimate aim of Hinduism is to set free from this Maya and mingle with Lord).. Here Lord Vishnu might be Allah for Muslims ( though their scriptures might not depict it). Also it would be ridiculous to fight for hegemony. Hinduism ( Sanatana Dharma) is way of life which contains set of eternal rules to uphold Dharma. Forgive those extremists.

Comment: This isn't really a question about Hinduism; obviously Hindu scripture doesn't say that every child is born Muslim.  So I'm closing your question.

Comment: @CZAbhinav: I guess, this is good question if you can remove the final paragraph. Infact, you can split the question into two parts one about the supposed importance/significance of *murti* and some other question about the last para.

Comment: @CZAbhinav: BTW, what the guy said about Islam is true. Koran say that every child is born muslim and the parents are the bad influence on the child who lead them astray into 'false religion'. We (Hindus) on the other hand accept every person to follow their religion and respect each others. http://islam101.com/dawah/newBorn.htm

Comment: @CZAbhinav I think you are talking the closing in wrong way. We are not here to criticise other religious SE site. It's there believe, As our believes based on Geeta and Ramayana, their on Quran. I think this question can work but not like this, try to read what Vineet said above.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Why you completely changed the title? It doesn't make sense as per body.

Comment: Actually every child born is Hindu. All other religions were founded by humans and have a "manufacturing date". Hinduism existed from the beginning of time. Hindus moved on to other religions as and when they were founded.